# Avoid "on update current_timestamp"

Tags: mysql, innodb

In MySQL, I want to have a table column of type `TIMESTAMP` but which does **NOT** update to the current timestamp on row updates.

My table is as simple as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lastAccess` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

It is then created by MySQL like the following:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE `test`;
```

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| lastAccess | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**How can I avoid the default value as well as the "on update" behavior?**

I use the InnoDB engine, if it matters.

MySQL version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: use a datetime field instead? timestamps are supposed to update themselves... that or include the field in the update , so it's `update ... set lastaccess=lastaccess`, causing it to update itself with its current value.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your comment. I decided for timestamp because it is (at least I thought it is) basically a UNIX timestamp (integer) and timezone-independent (not a calendar date + wall clock time, but a point in a world-wide time line) - Maybe I should use BIGINT after all for such timestamps...

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B already mentioned in the comments, the default behavior of `TIMESTAMP` is supposed to do exactly that.

I found out that when you set a default value in the table creation (or `ALTER` it), the default is no longer `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (obviously), **but also** the attribute "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" is removed (interestingly).

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lastAccess` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    --                              ^^^^^^^^^
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Also interestingly, if you set `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but omit the attribute, it is not set. It is only set silently when supplying **no default at all**.